# How to dock "Tool Options" to "Toolbox"?

Tags: gimp

The "Tool Options" and the "Toolbox" used to be in the same window, but it somehow broke apart. Can somebody give some hints as how to bring them together as one again?

[image: Tool Options and Toolbox as distinct windows]

Comment: Here's the help page that explains how https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-docks.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In the detached window (Tool Options), the name of the view (Paintbrush) is a grab-bar.

Put your cursor over the grab-bar, click and drag it to the dock area in the main window in order to reattach it to the main window.

Comment: Thanks for the info about superuser.com, will do as you suggested next time :)

Comment: On MS Windows Gimp 2.8.8 you have to click and drag the top tab's name ("Tool Options") and not the tool's name visible within the tab (e.g. "Paintbrush").

Comment: FYI, I am currently rocking GIMP 2.8.2 (Debian Wheezy), and the method detailed in the @OliverZendel comment (above) is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Upvoted for the graceful and kind way of informing the user of the forum topic - thank you!

Comment: I had to drop the window on the header of the dock area (the place where other tabs are seen), otherwise it just moves the window around.

Answer (score 77):

I'm using GIMP 2.8.1. I hope this will work for you:

Open the "Windows" menu and select "Single-Window Mode".

Simple ;)

Comment: Worked for me in GIMP 2.10, thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. The one above is outdated and confusing

Answer (score 10):

In the detached 'Tool Options' window, click on the red 'X' in the upper right corner to get rid of the window.  Then on the main Gimp screen, click on 'Windows,' then 'Dockable Dialogs.'  The first entry on its list will be 'Tool Options,' so click on that.  Then, Tool Options will appear as a tab in the window on the right side of the screen, along with layers and undo history.  Click and drag that tab over to the toolbox window on hte left and drop it inside.  The tool options will again be docked in the toolbox.

Comment: This doesn't work in GIMP 2.10.18 :-( Clicking and dragging the newly created Tool Options box onto the Toolbox doesn't dock it.

Comment: @Scooby-2 this is what just works for 2.10.18 https://stackoverflow.com/a/39064915/2445763